# Mounting dance pole to 55mm joist

Tags: joists, mounting

I'm setting my up partners dance pole under our house. I was either going to bolt 2 cuts of 90x35mm timber to either side of the existing joist (which is around 90x55). Then bolt the pole anchor to these bits of timber. I got wondering if some kind of steel angles mounted to the sides of the joist would be more appropriate. She's around 60Kg, she will be swinging around on it and I obviously want the thing to stay standing.

Comment: Some pictures of the pole mount and the desired mounting points would help even more. As would actually asking a question as noted in the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

If you can span across to the adjacent joists  that would probably be better.

Install your pieces of timber as blocking between joists and turn the mounting flange 45 degrees so that two screws go into the joist and two into the blocking.